# Is it possible that an iOS app with improper IDFA information passes App Store review?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, facebook-ios-sdk, idfa

I released an iOS app to App Store with Facebook SDK integrated.

During the submission, Itunes Connect asked me about IDFA:

> Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?

and I checked "No".

It passed App Store review successfully. There was no problem.

And after the submission, I found several links saying that, in my case, "Yes" should have been chosen for the question:

- [Does the Facebook SDK use IDFA for Mobile App Installs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998846/does-the-facebook-sdk-use-idfa-for-mobile-app-installs)
- [IOS application that uses Facebook SDK, which options should be selected on iTunes Connect IDFA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296913/ios-application-that-uses-facebook-sdk-which-options-should-be-selected-on-itun)
- https://www.facebook.com/help/audiencenetwork/414857395387956

My app don't serve advertisements but logs app installs and some events.

For instance, it contains codes like:

```
FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
FBSDKAppEvents.logEvent("Some events")
```

Now it seems quite obvious that my app uses IDFA and it was a mistake that I chose "No".

But the only thing confusing me is that my app passed review without any rejection.

***Is it possible that an iOS app with improper IDFA information passes App Store review?***

In my opinion, if Apple verifies IDFA information by human, I think it might be possible and my first submission was just lucky.

But if it is verified by the machine, then my answer ("No") was right and I am going to choose "No" again.

Is there anybody with similar experiences?

Comment: If they had a machine that could accurately tell if you were using IDFA information then they wouldn't even bother asking you.

Comment: @dan That makes sense too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I tried and got the answer.

I submitted the new version of my app with checking "Yes" to the IDFA question and it ***passed*** the review.

There was no changes related with FBSDK. That is, from the point of view of IDFA, those binaries can be considered to be same.

So the conclusion is:

- An iOS app with improper IDFA information can pass the App Store review (possibly Apple's mistake?)
- The fact that your app has passed the review without rejection doesn't guarantee you provided the right IDFA information. Don't believe history and always choose the right answer for that time